# Why do companies sponsor academic conferences?

Tags: conference, industry

In computer science, I often see companies sponsoring academic conferences. What do companies hope to gain from doing so, and is there any evidence that these hopes are fulfilled?

Comment: Really? This can he generalised to "why do companies advertise?".

Comment: @StephenTierney There might be other reasons, e.g. tax incentives. Also, I think you didn't read the second part of the question.

Answer (score 9):

Advertisement.

> is there any evidence that these hopes are fulfilled

Yes: if it didn't work, companies would slowly stop sponsoring.

Comment: "If it didn't work, companies would slowly stop sponsoring." -> yes I thought the same. I was hoping to have some more fine-grained information, e.g. impact of firm X sponsoring a conference on number of future applications to firm X from people attending the conference.

Answer (score 5):

Three reasons immediately come to mind:

1. Advertising. I have a *staggering* amount of marketing material from tech companies, and I don't even go to that many C.S.-type conferences. I've got things covered in stickers, a t-shirt or two, etc. And there is something to be fair for your firm being on people's minds associated with the conference.
2. Recruiting. It's very common for there to be recruiting events, tables, or the occasional pitch during a conference. It's an easy way to reach an audience of people who have a particular skill set you know you're looking for.
3. Supporting the community. Many commercial businesses are built on software and systems built and maintained by the community, their employees use that software, etc. If a conference sponsorship keeps that going, it's probably worth it as essentially an R&D expense.